# Using cookie on login Page using Struts 2

Tags: java, cookies, struts2, struts, httprequest

I'm learning Java EE and I have to remember logged-in users with a four-hour timed cookie.

I have to implement it this way because the cookie part is mandatory for my school.
I know my cookie is well created (in `LoginAction.java`) because I tested it in a custom action. (in my `login.jsp` I put a struts tag `<action ... executeResults="true"/>`.

I created an Interceptor named `LoginInterceptor` to intercept every attempt to access a page.

It intercepts the request quite right (yeah !) but then I can't check for cookies because my `HTTPServletRequest` is `null`.

How am I testing ?
I go to the index (`localhost.../myProject/`)
I log in with Remember me.

Have you got any ideas?

**`Index.jsp`:**

```
<% response.sendRedirect("AccueilAction.action"); %>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false"/>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <global-results>
            <result name="login">/WEB-INF/content/login.jsp</result>
        </global-results>  
    </package>

    <package name="com.yaka.yakaaerien.actions" namespace ="/" extends ="struts-default">
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="loginInterceptor" 
                         class="com.yaka.yakaaerien.interceptor.LoginInterceptor" />
            <interceptor-stack name="globalStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="loginInterceptor"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/> 
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors> 

        <action name="ActionsListAction" class="com.yaka.yakaaerien.actions.ActionsListAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="globalStack"/>
            <result>/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="AccueilAction" class="com.yaka.yakaaerien.actions.AccueilAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="globalStack"/>
            <result>/WEB-INF/content/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="LoginAction" class="com.yaka.yakaaerien.actions.LoginAction">
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/content/Accueil.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/WEB-INF/content/login.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/WEB-INF/content/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="GenerePasswordAction" class="com.yaka.yakaaerien.actions.GenerePasswordAction">
            <result>/WEB-INF/content/GenerePassword.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/content/result.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/WEB-INF/content/GenerePassword.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/WEB-INF/content/GenerePassword.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**`LoginAction.java`**  (getters and setters work, I don't show them, they were generated automatically):

```java
//imports....

public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware, ServletResponseAware {

    private boolean isAdmin = false;
    private String message;
    private String login;
    private String password;
    private String userID;
    private String remember;
    private UsersDAO usersDAO = new UsersDAO();
    public ArrayList<Users> list_users = new ArrayList<Users>();
    protected HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
    protected HttpServletResponse servletResponse;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception { 
       UsersDAO actions = new UsersDAO();
        List list_users = actions.get_users(login, password);
        Iterator i = list_users.iterator();
        Users user;
        if (list_users != null && !list_users.isEmpty()) {
            while(i.hasNext()){ 
                user = (Users)i.next();
                if (user.getUserIsAdm() != null && user.getUserIsAdm()) {
                    isAdmin = true;
                }

                // Permits to save the current logged Session
                //ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put("logged", user.getUserFirstName());
                System.out.println("success");
                if (remember.equals("true")) {
                    System.out.println("Registering new cookie");
                    Cookie userCookie = new Cookie("userID", user.getUserFirstName() + "," + user.getUserPassword());
                    userCookie.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 4);
                    servletResponse.addCookie(userCookie);
                }
                return SUCCESS;
            }
        }else {
            System.out.println("Adding actionError");
            addActionError("Erreur : Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe érroné.");
        }
        return ERROR;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate() {
        System.out.println("Form validation");

        System.out.println(remember);

        Map<String, List<String>> fields = getFieldErrors();
        fields = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        if (login == null || login.length() == 0) {
            addFieldError("coucou", "coucou");
        }
        if (password == null || password.length() == 0) {
            addFieldError("bad password", "bad password");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest hsr) {
        this.servletRequest = hsr;
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletResponse(HttpServletResponse hsr) {
        this.servletResponse = hsr;

    }

}
```

**`LoginInterceptor.java`:**

```
public class LoginInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
    private String cookied = "false";

    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("destroy");
    }

    public void init() {
        System.out.println("init");
    }

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception {
        if(ai.getAction() instanceof ServletRequestAware)
        {
            System.out.println("omg");
            this.servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest)ai.getInvocationContext().
                    get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST);
        }
        UsersDAO actions = new UsersDAO();
        System.out.println("Entering LoginInterceptor");
        if (getCookie("userID") != null) {
            System.out.println("Looking for cookie userID");
            String cookieValue = getCookie("userID").getValue();
            String login = cookieValue.substring(0, cookieValue.lastIndexOf(","));
            String password = cookieValue.substring(cookieValue.lastIndexOf(",") + 1);
            List list_users = actions.get_users(login, password);
            System.out.println("Checking cookie for user :" + login);
            Iterator i = list_users.iterator();
            Users currentUser;
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                currentUser = (Users) i.next();
                System.out.println(currentUser.getUserFirstName());
                System.out.println(getCookie("userID").getValue());
                if (currentUser.getUserFirstName().equals(login)) {
                    System.out.println("Cookie found !");
                    cookied = "true";
                    return ai.invoke();
                }
            }
        }
        return "login";
    }

    public Cookie getCookie(String name) {
        if (servletRequest != null) {
            if (servletRequest.getCookies() != null) {
                Cookie cookies[] = servletRequest.getCookies();
                Cookie requestedCookie = null;
                if (cookies != null) {
                    for (Cookie current : cookies) {
                        if (current.getName().equals(name)) {
                            requestedCookie = current;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return requestedCookie;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest hsr) {
        this.servletRequest = hsr;
    }

    public String getCookied() {
        return cookied;
    }

    public void setCookied(String cookied) {
        this.cookied = cookied;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interceptor you could get cookies like

```
Cookie[] cookies = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getCookies();
```

[`ServletRequestAware`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ServletRequestAware.html) interface is used with actions. To get access to the servlet environment use the [`ServletActionContext`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/ServletActionContext.html).

Comment: OK ! It works well now :D!

I think it is pretty hard to understand this.. I can't see that intereceptors catch actions request... but actions return a JSP.

So if i directly type in my web browser the link to another page, will it be intercepted too ?

A big thanks anyway :)

Comment: interceptors are used with actions, if you need to invoke something with a page use filters.

Comment: So, if i understand, to force redirection on the login page if someone type directyl an url to one of my page, i have to implement a filter too ?

Comment: @ogdabou What do you mean by a "URL to one of your page"? An S2 interceptor will be invoked for any action in a package or action configured with the interceptor in your interceptor stack.

Comment: For example :
Someone log in, he goes to the WhatEverPage.
He puts a favorite on it.
He logs out.. the cookie ends up after 4hours for me.
5 hours later he click on his favorite which has to redirect him on the WhatEverPage directly.
What happens there ? (the page, for example, can contains a <s:form action="blablaction"/> in it)

Comment: @ogdabou You need to configure the action for it or use `default-action-ref`. And also there's `UnknownHandler`.

Comment: @ogdabou It's intercepted, if there's a valid cookie it continues on like nothing happened. If there isn't a valid cookie, the user is redirected to the login page or whatever where they're logged in. You could also capture the original request and send a redirect on valid login if you wanted.

Comment: @RomanC ok i looked at the struts documentation for default-action-ref, and now i understand that struts automatically link a page to an action. So if he wants to jump on a page, it will be mapped with an action and my interceptor will work :).
Also you made me understand to handle errors (like 404 or action results error) with default-action-ref and UknownHandler and i thank your for that !

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you too, you confirm what i understood by bot both of you !

Comment: I'd like to add to @Dave comment that the favorite point to the correct action config, so it will pick up hence intercept.

Comment: Ok perfect, i'll try to summaries all you said in an answer to this question.
Thanks.